# How to access the properties(another object) of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm new to JS and I don't know how to access properties of an object, which are objects themselves. I have the following object(let´s call it '**a**'), where I want to access **-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX**.name for example.

[image]

I tried

```
console.log(a.-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX.name)
```

but it gave me an error, due to '-' being an exception. I know how to get the key names:

```
Object.keys(a)
```

but I cant figure out how to access their properties.

Could someone help me out? Actually, I would be fine if someone could give me a "keyword" I can google on for this topic(because I don't even know what to google). Googling 'Accessing objects inside objects' didn´t help me :(

Comment: This might help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `a["-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX"].name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Object access in JavaScript can be done via `.property` or `['property']`.

In your case, `['-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX']` will work due to syntactic limitations in using the `.` where the property name has to be a [valid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names).

The particular problem for `-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX` is the `-` sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Assuming i Would have    `kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX` instead of    `-kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX` ,accessing via the dot-nation should work, right?    `a.kk7b9q6FWN1VkCCflEX.name` ?                                       
    Sorry, will have to find out how to format comments, will edit asap. EDITED.